# Cannot get video to play in Ionic View iOS App

Tags: html5-video, ionic3, ionic-view

I can't seem to get a vanilla video to play when viewing an ionic web app through Ionic View.  The same code works correctly through a browser.

For example, the code below just shows empty space in Ionic View:

```
<video>
   <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

I've tried adding the video to the ionic project and trying to source it locally, but the result is the same.  Images, however, work fine.

Comment: I know this is old but have you tried ReactPlayer?